Yandex rewarded ad. не показывает рекламу
Когда я пишу код в on Ad Loaded showAd() реклама показывает бесконечность. Убираю код showAd() - не показывает реклама. Я смотрел видео https://ads.yandex.com/helpcenter/ru/dev/android/rewarded на 5:50 минуте как можно сделать чтоб показывало без фрагмента. Например когда открываешь страницу и чтоб показалась реклама. Короче куда вписать showAd() когда открываешь страницу?

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

видео 5.50 минут там показывают в фрагменте нужно поставить showAd()  чтоб показало рекламу .у меня нет фрагмента у меня обычный activity и мне showAd() куда то поставить

Покажите вашу попытку, куда вставляли в своём коде?

я пробовал туда вставлять

MobileAds.initialize(this) {println(">>>YandexAds initialize"rewardedAdLoader = RewardedAdLoader(this).apply {setAdLoadListener(object : RewardedAdLoadListener {
override fun onAdLoaded(ad: RewardedAd) {
showAd()вот сюда
rewardedAd = ad
println(">>>YandexAds anAdLoaded")
} override fun onAdFailedToLoad(error: AdRequestError) {
        loadRewardedAd()
    }
}


но показывает бесконечность

я просто не знаю как вызвать  showAd()  чтоб показывало один раз и при переключение на другую страницу .
